# Call Toolbox operators of ENVI from IDL code

Tags: clustering, classification, envi, idl

Is it possible to call the `clustering/classification` algorithms included in the toolbox of `ENVI` (gui) from `IDL` (source code) and how?

Comment: read this http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/CLASS_DOIT.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this example in `ENVI's documentation` which does exactly what I was looking for in `IDL`: http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/enviclassificationaggregationtask.html.